# Add CodeFixProvider to existing Nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to add a Roslyn Analyzer and Code Fix Provider to an existing project, `ApiEndpoints.csproj` that is distributed as a nuget package.

When consuming the nuget package in a new Visual Studio instance, the Analyzer is clearly working, but the corresponding Code Fix Provider does not appear int the list of Code Fixes.  **How can I troubleshoot and get my Code Fix Provider to correctly register with Visual Studio?**

I originally built the Analyzer & Code Fix Provider in a new project via the *Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard)* Project Template.  When I bundle that into a nuget package, deploy locally, and consume it from a new Studio instance, the Analyzer works and the Code Fix Provider recommends a solution:

`ApiEndpoints.Analyzer.csproj`:
[image]

However, when I move the Analyzer and Code Fix Provider class to the main `ApiEndpoints.csproj` that is bundled with other classes, only the Analyzer seems to register, there's only the option to Suppress, my Code Fix Provider isn't in the list:

`ApiEndpoints.csproj`:

[image]

#### What I've tried so far:

1. I can attach a Visual Studio debugger hosting the Analyzer/Fix Provider to a different instance of Studio that's consuming it.  Break points in the Analzyer are getting hit, but nothing in the Code Fix Provider.  So I don't think an exception in my Code Fix Provider is preventing registration.
2. I've gone line-by-line in the `ApiEndpints.csproj` vs `ApiEndpoints.Analyzers.csproj` and aligned `SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking` (true), `GeneratePackageOnBuild` (true), `IncludeBuildOutput` (true).   These changes didn't help.
3. Restarted both Visual Studio instances numerous times.  When initially consuming a nuget package with an Analyzer I've seen the Analyzer not show up until Visual Studio is restarted.  But multiple restarts didn't fix the Code Fix Provider
4. Changed the Analyzer's `DiagnosticId` a few times and ensured the Code Fix Provider was referencing it.
5. Deployed the same Analyzer + CodeFixProvider from different projects (*Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard)* vs Class Library).  Works in one but not the other, which makes me think it's not a problem with the Code Fix Provider, but some kind of registration/plumbing code/config.

#### Summary

**How can I troubleshoot and get my Code Fix Provider to correctly register with Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't package libraries and analyzers/fixers in the same assembly or even the same package.

Besides forcing your users to take a run-time dependency on the analyzers/fixers and their dependencies, the tooling does not support that use case.

You should package them in their own packages and have the library package take a dependency on the analyzers/fixers package.